# Can Python Scripts with os.system be converted to a standalone exe?

Tags: python, operating-system, exe, execution

I want to convert a Python Script into an exe File.
I used Pyinstaller but when I run the exe, it opens a console and closes immediately. The script contains os.system, which means that it executes commands to the console. Could it be that this is the problem? Where is my mistake?

```
import os 
import pandas 
import twitterscraper 

os.system("twitterscraper Trump --limit 10 -c --output=Trump.csv")

df = pandas.read_csv("Trump.csv") 
print(df)
```

Comment: yes, use `pyinstaller` . Ex: `pyinstaller -F file.py`

Comment: Try adding something which forces the cli window to remain open. A simple example would be `input('[ENTER] to exit program')`